# Regex to match tag contents while simultaneously omitting leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: regex, whitespace, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds, removing-whitespace

I am trying to write a regex that matches entire contents of a tag, minus any leading or trailing whitespace.  Here is a boiled-down example of the input:

> `<tag`>     text    `</tag`>

I want only the following to be matched (note how the whitespace before and after the  match has been trimmed):

> "text"

I am currently trying to use this regex in .NET (Powershell):

```
(?<=<tag>(\s)*).*?(?=(\s)*</tag>)
```

However, this regex matches "text" plus the leading whitespace inside of the tag, which is undesired. How can I fix my regex to work as expected?

Comment: Don't use .*? in the middle there. That' will consume whitespace. Use the alphanumeric escape instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the lookarounds; they just make the job more complicated than it needs to be.  Instead, use a capturing group to pick out the part you want:

```
<tag>\s*(.*?)\s*</tag>
```

The part you want is available as `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the type of tip I was looking for, and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

[You should not use regext to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm).

Use a parser instead.

Also:
[Regex to remove body tag attributes (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817821/regex-to-remove-body-tag-attributes-c)

Also also: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

If all that doesn't convince you, then don't use the dot in the middle of your expression. Use the alphanumeric escape. Your dot is consuming whitespace. Use \w (I think) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment.  I was only looking for some regex pointers on this particular question; however, because of your answer and the links you posted, I am going to look into using .NET's XmlReader to parse our KML files instead of the way we're currently doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use these regular expressions to strip trailing and leading whitespaces. `/^\s+/` and `/\s+$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
        test = "<tag>     test    </tag>";
        string pattern3 = @"<tag>(.*?)</tag>";
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", Regex.Match(test,pattern3).Groups[1].Value.Trim());
```