# Removing commented lines from InnerText

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

i'm currently using the below code which extracts the InnerText, however, what happens is i'm stuck with a bunch of comment out lines of html `<--`  how do I remove these using the code below?

```
HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(htmlURL);

foreach (var script in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
    script.Remove();
HtmlNode body = htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
resultingHTML = body.InnerText.ToString();
```

Comment: Your tags provide enough context for the question. Please avoid including them in your question headings.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the inner text that the comments make a difference? Certainly the other HTML tags would cause you trouble as well if you're not trying to render the HTML directly (in which case the comments would be ignored)

Comment: I store the innertext inside a mysqlDB and it just eats up space and takes longer to manually process if the criteria passes for the text

Comment: I've updated my answer based on something that actually makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818641/635634) is probably a better answer:

```
public static void RemoveComments(HtmlNode node)
{
    foreach (var n in node.ChildNodes.ToArray())
        RemoveComments(n);
    if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment)
        node.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just filter the nodes by comment nodes and call remove on them.

```
var rootNode = doc.DocumentNode;
var query = rootNode.Descendants().OfType<HtmlCommentNode>().ToList();
foreach (var comment in query)
{
    comment.Remove();
}
```