# How to skip paragraphs with comments in XPath expression?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to scrape websites like [this](https://www.przewodnik-katolicki.pl/Archiwum/2013/Przewodnik-Katolicki-49-2013/Temat-numeru/Rozjasnij-dzieciom-przyszlosc) with the following Xpath expression:

```
.//div[@class="tresc"]/p[not(starts-with(text(), "<!--"))]
```

The thing is that the first paragraph is a comment section, so I'd like to skip it:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Normal</w:View>
<w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
<w:HyphenationZone>21</w:HyphenationZone>
<w:PunctuationKerning />
<w:ValidateAgainstSchemas />
<w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid
<w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent
<w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
<w:Compatibility>
<w:BreakWrappedTables />
<w:SnapToGridInCell />
<w:WrapTextWithPunct />
<w:UseAsianBreakRules />
<w:DontGrowAutofit />
</w:Compatibility>
<w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]-->
```

Unfortunately, my expression does not skip the paragraph with comments. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing commented lines from InnerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106177/removing-commented-lines-from-innertext)

Comment: actually choroba's answer solved my issue. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are not part of `text()`, they constitute a node of their own: `comment()`. To exclude `p`'s that contain comments, use

```
p[not(comment())]
```