# HtmlAgilityPack get contents in a comments line

Tags: html, dom, get, comments

I want get content value in a comment line string:

```
<!-- <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://**.com/za6dc7.mp4" />-->

 Dim node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@item='contentURL']")
 TextBox1.Text += node.GetAttributeValue("content", String.Empty)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible. I would rather process all comment nodes like stated here [How to select node types which are HtmlNodeType.Comment using HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818404/how-to-select-node-types-which-are-htmlnodetype-comment-using-htmlagilitypack) and then create new HTMLDocument for each comment's contents, then extract nesessary information out of it.

UPD: HAP is fast, so that wouldn't take performance down.